# protobuf-lite:3.0.0 is incompatible with Protocol Buffers v3.0.0

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

I implement protobuf in Android like the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.0'
```

I define a .protoc like the following:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Test {
  string str = 1;
}
```

The version of Protocol Buffers is v3.0.0:

```
protoc-3.0.0-win32.zip
```

I use the following cmd to generate java code:

```
protoc --java_out=./ test.proto
```

The generate java is full of error:

1. com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 cant be found
2. com.google.protobuf.Descriptors cant be found
3. com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet cant be found
4. com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder cant be found
5. com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry cant be found

How can i do?

protobuf-lite:3.0.0 cant be changed(historical reasons)